# Question about Linear Transformation notation : L(U,W) vs. L(W,U)

Tags: linear-transformations

Hey Exchange community,

We have finite-dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$ with ordered bases $B$ and $A$ respectively.

Is it true/false that $L(V,W)=L(W,V)$?

Just wondering if someone could articulate what the difference is between the two notations. Having someone write it down as if they were verbally explaining it to someone would really help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbols $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ indicates the linear transformations from vector space $V$ into vector space $W$, and the analogous statement is made for $\mathcal{L}(W,V)$.  If $V$ and $W$ are not the same space (e.g. isomorphic) then you don't in general have the same maps going from $V$ to $W$ as you do from $W$ to $V$.  For instance, if $V$ were $2$-dimensional and $W$ were $3$-dimensional then the linear maps in $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ could be represented by $3\times 2$ matrices, but the maps in $\mathcal{L}(W,V)$ would be $2\times 3$ matrices.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!

Comment: Just to add, $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ and $\mathcal{L}(W,V)$ don't even have to have the same dimension (i.e, they are not isomorphic) if $V$ or $W$ is infinite-dimensional. For example, if $V=\mathbb{R}$ and $W = \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}$

Comment: You can indicate if the answer solves your problem in the icon of check at left side to this answer.

Comment: I haven't learned what the + in the circle means just yet. How do you insert symbols such as that into comments on this forum?

Comment: @DavidSouth This [link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is the reference page for math typesetting on this site.  The $\oplus$ symbols is called a "direct sum", and you can read up on it on Wikipedia or your textbook.  Thanks for accepting my answer!

Comment: Okay, thank you! And no problem :).

Answer (score 0):

$\mathcal{L}(U,W)=\{T\colon U\to W/ T \mbox{ is a linear transformation }\}$
$\mathcal{L}(W,U)=\{T\colon W\to U/ T \mbox{ is a linear transformation }\}$

There are different because $Im(\mathcal{L}(U,V))\subset U$ and $Im((\mathcal{L}(V,U))\subset V$ and $ U, V$ nor always will be subsets of the same space.

For example $\mathcal{L}(U,\mathbb{K})$ obviusly not equal to $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{K},U)$